# SSH Tunnel not working with VPN

Tags: ssh, vpn, tunnel

I'm using my home **macmini** connected to a AWS EC2 with **reverse tunnel**. I start the tunnel with a LaunchDaemon using this config:

```
<array>
        <string>ssh</string>
        <string>-NT</string>
        <string>-o</string>
        <string>ServerAliveInterval=60</string>
        <string>-R</string>
        <string>6000:localhost:22</string>
        <string>-i</string>
        <string>~/.ssh/tunnelaws.pem</string>
        <string>user@mydomain</string>
    </array>
```

It's working fine: if I connect to my EC2 I can simply do `ssh -p 6000 user@localhost` and I connect to my macmini.

The problem is, when I connect to **ExpressVPN** in macmini, I can't use this tunnel anymore.

any idea?

Comment: @RohitGupta what on earth, an SSH tunnel and a VPN are different things, see the question and use google to show you that the questioner's usage of the terms ssh tunnel and  VPN are correct

Comment: Oops, I didn't spot the SSH in the title.